# Backgroundcolor of segmented-control element does not span entire width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a segmented control with 3 different "categories". When a certain category is "active", I want their background to be entirely blue. This is the case for "tab1" but unfortunately, something goes wrong when "tab2" or "tab3" is active, because their background is not entirely blue. The background also contains small grey strips and I have no idea how to get rid of those.

I put this code in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vooj53xt/1/
The jsfiddle contains the same exact components three times. The only difference between the three components is which element is activated. As you can see, when "tab2" or "tab3" is activated, their background is not entirely blue. There is also a small strip that is grey. These grey strips, however, are unwanted. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

The HTML looks like this:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                    <ul class="segmented-control">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a  href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#tab3" >Tab 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The accompanying CSS looks like this:

```
body {
background-color: #f8f4f0;
padding-bottom: 70px;
padding-top: 70px;  
}

.segmented-control {
    border: 2px solid #51cbeb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.segmented-control li {
    border-right: 2px solid #51cbeb;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32%;
}

.segmented-control li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.segmented-control .active {
    background-color: #51cbeb;
}    

.segmented-control li a {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.demo-page {
    margin: 120px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change display property, like this:

```
.segmented-control {
 display:table;
}
.segmented-control li {
display:table-cell;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vooj53xt/9/
Problem is caused by using of inline-block...https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thank you! This fixes the problem indeed. Before reading your comment, a friend of mine told me I could remove the whitelines between the <li> elements and oddly enough this also fixes the problem. I will make sure to checkout your link soon!

Comment: Hey nevermind, sorry for disturbing you again but I am experiencing one problem with your solution that I didn't have with the code I initially posted.
If the length of the text in the elements is not the same, the width of the different "segments" also differs. Is there an easy fix to this?
You can see the problem in the first segmented-control here: http://jsfiddle.net/vooj53xt/18/

Comment: @Simon, well... if you need same widths - you can set it... (2x33%, and last tab 34%? http://jsfiddle.net/vooj53xt/23/

Answer (score 1):

You can set `font-size: 0;` to the `ul` and reset it on `li`, to fix the white space bug on inline block.

```
.segmented-control {
  font-size: 0;
}

.segmented-control li {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I am going to "accept" nevermind's answer because I think it feels a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/fpuc8010/2/).  I just changed `display:block` to `float:left` - and added `clearfix` class to the `ul` tag classes and changed width to 33.34% for the `li` tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
            <ul class="segmented-control clearfix">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
            <ul class="segmented-control clearfix">
                <li class=""><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
            <ul class="segmented-control clearfix">
                <li class=""><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a ref="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #f8f4f0;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
/* Segmented control */
 .segmented-control {
    border: 2px solid #51cbeb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.segmented-control li {
    border-right: 2px solid #51cbeb;
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.3333334%;
}
.segmented-control li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
.segmented-control .active {
    background-color: #51cbeb;
}
.segmented-control li a {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.demo-page {
    margin: 120px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Mia. This comes very close to what I want. While I was playing with the width, however, I saw that sometimes a little glitch pops up. You can see it here: http://imgur.com/K3gYzg7

Any idea how this can be resolved?

Comment: yeah you can try 33.34 on the li tag or a little more or something - it's trying to divide the area evenly sometimes it's glitchy I guess, but on all my browsers the fiddle looks good

Comment: Actually I updated it to width: 33.3333334%; and that seemed to get rid of that space glitch.